# Have mutt check a directory for new mail brought by fetchmail

Tags: imap, mutt, fetchmail

Is there a way to have mutt check a directory for new emails brought in my fetchmail rather than then my gmail imap? Having mutt check on demand is slow, basically I just reload the imap folder which contains a lot of mail.

Is this the solution I'm even looking for? Can someone point me to a tutorial or instruct me on how to do this?